# MS Word: Trying to dynamically update a text field when I change pictures

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge, word-template

I create scannable QR codes cards in word for users to report problems. Each time I change the QRCode image, I have to change the Caption under the image to match it to the computer we are labeling. Typing this caption takes time, as 9 cards fit on a single page and each has to be updated when we insert/change the image. I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically change the caption each time I change the picture. I am adding an image as an example below. ANY Help would be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3dYh.png)

I have tried looking at VB to set a label and reference the image filename (which us created with the computer name) and just remove the extension, but I can't figure out how to set the properties for the object and dynamically link them. I have little VB.Net scripting and haven't used it in almost 10 years.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Have you tried using the VBA macro recorder to generated the required VBA code for you when you don't know where to start?

Comment: Just want to check, are you looking for a MS Word/vba , or are you looking for vb.net help?  You've tagged the question as vb.net then asked about scripting (btw, VB.Net scripting isn't really a thing).  Tagging the question correctly will likely get you better answers

Comment: How are you inputting the data for the DISPLAYBARCODE field in Word? It seems to me the whole exercise could be done via a label mailmerge using an Excel data source with one each of a MERGEBARCODE field and a MERGEFIELD field per label, both pointing to the same data field. No VBA/VB.Net code required.

Comment: The method is non-scripted thus far, which is why we are attempting to automate. The process is just right clicking on the picture and selecting "Change Picture" so that it preserves the aspect ratio dimensions and then manually typing in the name for the computer. 
Obviously this introduces increased chance of human error by typing each label.

Hursey - I will remove the VB.Net



macropod - I have not used much in Merging, but I am more than happy to use this if I can make it work.
Astafiev - I haven't figured out how to make the macro reference the picture and text field

Answer (score 0):

Assumning you need a solution for manual data entry into your 9 cards/labels (even though a mailmerge would work better for bulk card/label creation), if you configure each of them with:

- a DISPLAYBARCODE field where your image shows the QR code; and
- a text content control where your image shows the serial #,

the following ContentControlOnExit macro, placed in the 'ThisDocument' code module of your document or its template will automatically update the QR code in each label/card to match the serial # whenever its content control is exited.

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
With CCtrl.Range.Cells(1).Range
  .Fields(1).Code.Text = "DISPLAYBARCODE " & CCtrl.Range.Text & " QR \q 3"
  .Fields.Update
End With
End Sub
```